# Copying file from s3:// to local file system

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig, hdfs

I am an aws newbie. I created a cluster and ssh'ed into the master node. When I am trying to copy files from s3://my-bucket-name/ to local file://home/hadoop folder in pig using:

```
cp s3://my-bucket-name/path/to/file file://home/hadoop
```

i get the error:

> 2013-06-08 18:59:00,267 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 29 99: Unexpected internal error. AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be s pecified as the username or password
>   (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting t he fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or
>   fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

I can not even ls into my s3 bucket. I set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY without success. Also I could not locate config file for pig to set the appropriate fields.

Any help please?

Edit:
I tried to load file in pig using the full s3n:// uri

```
grunt> raw_logs = LOAD 's3://XXXXX/input/access_log_1' USING TextLoader a
s (line:chararray);
grunt> illustrate raw_logs;
```

and I get the following error:

> 2013-06-08 19:28:33,342 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengi ne.HExecutionEngine -
>   Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:/// 2013-06-08 19:28:33,404
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengi
>   ne.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100
>   optimistic? fal se 2013-06-08 19:28:33,404 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengi
>   ne.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before
>   optimization: 1 2013-06-08 19:28:33,405 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengi
>   ne.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after
>   optimization: 1 2013-06-08 19:28:33,405 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState -  Pig script settings are
>   added to the job 2013-06-08 19:28:33,429 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengi
>   ne.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler -
>   mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percen t is not set, set to default
>   0.3 2013-06-08 19:28:33,430 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator - Error  reading data. Internal
>   error creating job configuration. java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal
>   error creating job configuration.
>           at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getExamples(ExampleGenerator.java
>   :160)
>           at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1244)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.
>   java:722)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigS
>   criptParser.java:591)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScript
>   Parser.java:306)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.j
>   ava:189)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.j
>   ava:165)
>           at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
>           at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:500)
>           at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:114)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187) 2013-06-08 19:28:33,432 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 29 97: Encountered IOException. Exception : Internal error creating job configurati on. Details at logfile:
>   /home/hadoop/pig_1370719069857.log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you should use the s3n protocol (unless you stored the files on s3 using the s3 protocol) - s3 is used for block storage (i.e. similar to hdfs, only on s3) and s3n is for native s3 file system (i.e. you get what you see there).

You can use distcp or a simple pig load from s3n. You can either supply the access & secret in hadoop-site.xml as specified in the exception you got (see here for more info: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), or you can add them to the uri:

```
raw_logs = LOAD 's3n://access:secret@XXXXX/input/access_log_1' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);
```

Make sure that your secret doesn't contain back-slashes - otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Also, do I need to edit hadoop-site.xml everytime I create a new cluster?

Comment: Can I make the s3n file public and then simply copy without using the keys?

Comment: When you create a jobflow in EMR it has your credentials already on it.

If you are using Roles for EC2, the credentials are handled by the InstanceController(I think that's what it's called). If you are using your root account or IAM user, these credentials should already be in the site.xml.

Answer (score 4):

`cp` in

```
cp s3://my-bucket-name/path/to/file file://home/hadoop
```

is unaware of S3.

You may want to use:

```
s3cmd get s3://some-s3-bucket/some-s3-folder/local_file.ext ~/local_dir/
```

Not sure why `s3cmd cp ...` does not do what it needs to do, but `s3cmd get ...` works.
And `man s3cmd` has:

```
   s3cmd get s3://BUCKET/OBJECT LOCAL_FILE
          Get file from bucket
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this exact same error and finally hit on the solution.  However, I changed two things at once so I am not sure if both are required (certainly one of them is).

First, I made sure my S3 data and my EMR system were in the same region.  When I had this problem, my data was in US East and the EMR was in US West.  I standardized on US East (Virginia), a.k.a. us-east-1, a.k.a US Standard, a.k.a. DEFAULT, a.k.a. N. Virginia.  This may not have been required, but it did not hurt.

Second, when I got the error, I started pig by following the steps in one of the videos and gave it a "-x local" option.  It turns out that the "-x local" seems guaranteed to prevent the access to s3 (see below).

**The solution is start pig with no parameters.**

I hope this helps.

Gil

---

```
hadoop@domU-12-31-39-09-24-66:~$ pig -x local
2013-07-03 00:27:15,321 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1-amzn (rexported) compiled Jun 24 2013, 18:37:44
2013-07-03 00:27:15,321 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/hadoop/pig_1372811235317.log
2013-07-03 00:27:15,379 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2013-07-03 00:27:15,793 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - 
Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///

grunt>  ls s3://xxxxxx.xx.rawdata
2013-07-03 00:27:23,463 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. AWS Access Key ID and
Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId
or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/pig_1372811235317.log

grunt> quit

hadoop@domU-12-31-39-09-24-66:~$ pig
2013-07-03 00:28:04,769 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1-amzn (rexported) compiled Jun 24 2013, 18:37:44
2013-07-03 00:28:04,771 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/hadoop/pig_1372811284764.log
2013-07-03 00:28:04,873 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2013-07-03 00:28:05,639 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - 
Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://10.210.43.148:9000
2013-07-03 00:28:08,765 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: 10.210.43.148:9001

grunt>  ls s3://xxxxxx.xx.rawdata
s3://xxxxxx.xx.rawdata/rawdata<r 1>  19813
s3://xxxxxx.xx.rawdata/rawdata.csv<r 1> 19813
grunt>
```